# Pointing 2 subdomain on same ip but I want it both to work in different directory

Tags: server, apache2, virtualhost

I've 2 sub domains both are pointing on same ip and server and currently pointing to /var/www/html as root but I want one of them to point in subdirectory like /var/www/html/anothersub :

So I created new file in sites-available folder : anothersub.mydomain.com.conf

added this above code in it :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName anothersub.mydomain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/anothersub
        <Directory /var/www/html/anothersub>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/red-error.log

        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/red-access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

and run commands : 
sudo a2dissite anothersub.mydomain.com.conf
sudo a2ensite anothersub.mydomain.com.conf
sudo service apache2 restart

but still my both domains are pointing to same root directory

Answer (score 2):

Add a slash to the end of the Directory path:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/anothersub/>
```

Make sure both VirtualHost files are in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled:

```
ls -al /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

If one of the VirtualHosts should not be in this directory enable it:

```
a2ensite anothersub.conf
```

Note that the config file has to have the file extension .conf, otherwise it will not work!
Restart your apache2 webserver

```
service apache2 restart
```

Call both domains, e. g. with curl:

```
curl -I mydomain.com
curl -I anothersub.mydomain.com
```

If it doesn't work have a look at the apache log files:

```
tailf /var/log/apache2/red-access.log
```

Hope this helps